# Java Establish connection to a network computer

Tags: java

I have a program that needs to read/write files to/from a network computer. Sometimes however the program cannot access the folder on the network computer. Currently, to fix this issue, I go into windows explorer's network section, click the computer, enter my credentials, and then my program is able to read and write to this computer without a problem. Is there a way to allow Java to ask for these credentials or a way to automatically send these credentials using java? I am using Win7 and Win7 embedded on the network computer.

Comment: you can use NTLM authentication for accessing files in network. if your computers are connected to active directory you may even use kerberos. there is an api called jcifs you can use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://jcifs.samba.org/ which is a library for accessing remote CIFS shares. This allows you to set username and password and works on any platform (not just windows) It works without needing to mount a drive.